# Pause within a list leaves blank space between items in quarto reveal

Tags: quarto, reveal.js

In Quarto markdown I am creating a revealjs presentation and I want a list in which the last item is shown after the others. If I put a pause within the list (or I put the last item within a fragment) I get extra space before the last item. This is a MWE:

```
---
format:
   revealjs:
      slide-transition: slide
self-contained: true
---

## List without pause
- First item
- Second item
- Third item

## List with pause
- First item
- Second item

. . .

- Third item
```

Is there a way to have the last item shown after a pause and with the same spacing as the others?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just remove the bottom margins for the list when using them with "pause".

Also note that `.pause` class I have used for the slide that contains lists with pause.

**styles.css**

```css
.pause ul {
  margin-bottom: 0 !important;
}
```

**presentation.qmd**

```
---
format:
   revealjs:
    css: styles.css
    slide-transition: slide
self-contained: true
---

## List without pause
- First item
- Second item
- Third item

## List with pause {.pause}

- First item
- Second item

. . .

- Third item
```

---

[image]